# check different nodes and echo accordingly

Tags: php, xpath

i have index of pages  with slight different structure.i am trying to loop through many pages and to do following:-

1.if `td[2]` has span class thn to echo the class.
2.if `td[2]` has img nodes then to count the number of nodes having `src`  of `http://example.com/img/star01.giff`  and to echo the total.

i am able to do the 1st part but not the 2nd.

**pagetype1**

```
<tbody>

<tr>
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td>
        <span class="star5-05">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name2</td>
    <td>
        <span class="star5-05">
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**pagetype2**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>
            <img alt="" src="http://example.com/img/star01.gif">
            <img alt="" src="http://example.com/img/star01.gif">
            <img alt="" src="http://example.com/img/star01.gif">
            <img alt="" src="http://example.com/img/star01.gif">
            <img alt="" src="http://example.com/img/star02.gif">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>
            <img alt="" src="http://example.comimg/star01.gif">
            <img alt="" src="http://example.comimg/star01.gif">
            <img alt="" src="http://example.comimg/star01.gif">
            <img alt="" src="http://example.comimg/star01.gif">
            <img alt="" src="http://example.com/img/star02.gif">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**my code**

```
foreach( $my_nodes as $my_node )
    {
    $tmp=$my_xpath->query('td[1]',$my_node);

    if ($tmp->length>0)
        {
        $tmp=$tmp->item(0)->textContent;

        if ($tmp=="Name1")
            {   
            $chkstars=$my_xpath->query('td[2]/span/@class',$my_node);
            if ($chkstars->length>0)
                {
                $tmp_stars=$chkstars->item(0)->textContent;
                }
                else 
                {
                $tmp_stars=$my_xpath->evaluate('count(//td[2]/img[@src="http://www.example.com/img/star01.gif"]),$my_node )');
                }   
            echo $tmp_stars."<br>";
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: `$my_xpath->evaluate('count(//img[@src="http://example.comimg/star01.gif"]));`

Comment: where should i put this count(//img[@src="http://example.comimg/star01.gif"])

Comment: Or if you want to count img in that row only - `$my_xpath->evaluate('count(.//img[@src="http://example.comimg/star01.gif"]),$my_node );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the unswer is Xpath `count(.//img[@src="http://example.comimg/star01.gif"])`. All the code only for testing purpose

```
$my_xpath = new DOMXPath($my_doc);
$my_nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//tbody/tr' );  
foreach( $my_nodes as $my_node )
{
$tmp=$my_xpath->query('td[2]',$my_node);
    if ($tmp->length>0)
    {
    $tmp=$tmp->item(0)->textContent;    
        if ($chkstars=$my_xpath->evaluate('string(td[2]/span/@class)',$my_node))
               echo 'class: ' . $chkstars . "\n";
        if($count = $my_xpath->evaluate('count(.//img[@src="http://example.comimg/star01.gif"])',$my‌​_node ))
               echo 'count: ' . $count . "\n";
    }
}
```

[demo](https://eval.in/586647)   (Change to str1 or str for different xml))

Comment: i altered the code...plz se my code...it still doesn't echo correctly...i need it to echo the tmp_stars if the td[1] is Name1